# Find by two columns where one contains null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Following documentation of spring-data that is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) there is possibility of creating custom queries using naming convention of methods. 
I can find record by some value in `column1` using `findByColumn1` and find objects that contains `NULL` in `column2` by using `findByColumn2IsNull`, but when I try to do something like

```
MyResult result = findByColumn1AndColumn2IsNull("expectedValueOfColumn1");
```

it returns results that contains `column2` property that is set to non-null value.

Can somebody tell me if I'm using the query method wrong, or there is some other issue here?

Comment: *try to do something like*... And then what happens? An exception, you see nothing or ???

Comment: Is your column2 nullable?

Comment: Yes, it is nullable.

Comment: A stack trace will help us figure out the problem.

Comment: There is no stacktrace or any kind of error in logs. That's why I didn't posted it here.